# I am going back and forth between which cadences I hear in this excerpt

Tags: theory

I am listening to this audio excerpt and I hear it in duple (but I also mapped it out in quadruple). The problem I am facing is that I know there are two cadences. I have a full cadence for the first one and I think the last one is a half cadence (?)

Thanks for all your guys' help! I am learning each day with music.

https://streamable.com/e7unt

The second audio listening I am torn between what the time signature is supposed to be. I think it ends on either a deceptive cadence or a half cadence.

https://streamable.com/75r9oj

Again, thanks tremendously for all your help!

Comment: 1st vid is oops. And the question is questionnable on this site.

Comment: Yes, these quiz questions are getting old! And working from audio files instead of scores is basically a transcription request, or just asking someone else to do the aural skills stuff.